# Python regex show all characters between span

Tags: python, regex

I want to view everything between span=(179, 331), How to display this ? In advance thanks

```
new_v1 = re.compile(r'Sprzedawca:')
new_v2 = re.compile(r'lp ')
print(new_v1.search(txt))
print(new_v2.search(txt))
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(179, 199), match='Sprzedawca: Nabywca:'>
<re.Match object; span=(328, 331), match='lp '>
```

Comment: Please also include the starting text you want to search.

Comment: np.

Data wystawienia: 2011-04-14
Data sprzedazy: 2011-04-14
Miejsce wystawienia:
Sprzedawca: Nabywca:
M- gfsfsdg ,,” Sp .z 0. 0.
dfsggg 19 hhhhhh 1
45-757 Opole 15-186 Bialystok
NIP: 11111111111 NIP: 22222222222
lp |Nazwa towaru lub uslugi |PPPPP /Jm__|Tlos¢ |Cena Stawka Wart. netto |Wart. VAT | Wart. Brutto
netto VAT
1 | Mg | 1,500 800,00 * 1 200,00 -* 1 200,00
2  |rrrMg {0,500 | 8 000,00 23% 4 000,00 920,00 4 920,00

Comment: I need to find start and end text, then everything between display. I wanted to use Span, but I do not know if it's a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how to match text between start and stop. I chose a simple text, adjust the regexp for your needs:

```
import re

RE = re.compile(r'(?:Start)(.*)(?:End)')
# re.compile(..., flags=re.DOTALL) to match also newlines

match = RE.search('testStartTextBetween123ABCxyzEndtest')
if match:
    print(match.group(1)) # TextBetween123ABCxyz
```

There are three groups in the regexp (groups are in parentheses). The first one matches the start of text mark, the second one matches everything and the last one mathes the end of text mark.

The `(?:` notation means the resulting match is not saved. Only the middle group is saved as the first (and only) matched subgroup. This corresponds to `match.group(1)`

Comment: why I can not see anything 

print(txt)

 Data wystawienia: 2011-04-14 Data sprzedazy: 2011-04-14 Miejsce wystawienia: Sprzedawca: Nabywca: M- gfsfsdg ,,” Sp .z 0. 0. dfsggg 19 hhhhhh 1 45-757 Opole 15-186 Bialystok NIP: 11111111111 NIP: 22222222222 lp |Nazwa towaru lub uslugi |PPPPP /Jm__|Tlos¢ |Cena Stawka Wart. netto |Wart. VAT | Wart. Brutto netto VAT 1 | Mg | 1,500 800,00 * 1 200,00 -* 1 200,00 2 |rrrMg {0,500 | 8 000,00 23% 4 000,00 92

if I use

RE = re.compile(r'(?:Sprzedawca)(.*)(?:lp)')
match = RE.search(txt)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))

Nothing on the exit: /

Comment: @TMask It works for me. Are there newlines in the string? If yes, see the re.DOTALL comment I added to the code.

Comment: Wonderful, I did not notice the comment probably time to take a break  ;)

Comment: @TMask You're fine, I added it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

The function call `new_v1.search(txt)` returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) which has various attributes. You can call its methods to retrieve various facts about the match and the matched text. The simplest way to pull out the text which matched is probably

```py
print(new_v1.search(txt).group(0))
```

but you could certainly also pull out the `start` and `end` attributes and extract the span yourself:

```py
matched = new_v1.search(txt)
print(txt[matched.start():matched.end()])
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/CFXjx2

Of course, with a trivial regex, the matched text will be exactly the regex itself; perhaps you are actually more interested in where exactly in the string the match was found.